# How do I keep the toolbar at top when I scroll? (Android Studio)

Tags: xml, android-studio, scroll, toolbar

I have created a `toolbar` that works fine for navigation. The problem is that when I scroll the `toolbar` doesn't remain pinned to the top. I scroll away from it. Naturally I would like to keep it at the top at all times. I think the problem is that I have the `toolbar` xml within the `scrollview` hierarchy. It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context="com.nollvision.slothmode.nollvision.DetailActivity2">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/detail2_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <ImageView... AND SO ON....
```

I have tried to change the structure to Constraint->ScrollView->Constraint->children. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.nollvision.slothmode.nollvision.DetailActivity2">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail2_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView...AN SO ON
```

The result is that the `toolbar` completely disappears and that the layout is all over the place. Still, is this the right way to proceed, or is there a better and foremost an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a FrameLayout for this.

Something like this:-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.nollvision.slothmode.nollvision.DetailActivity2">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/detail2_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: Awesome man, that worked like a charm! Thanks a bunch for taking the time to help me out @rohiththammaiah! A bit of tinkering with the layout, of course, but the toolbar stays on top now. One thing to point out though for those with the same problem is to set `android:elevation="5dp"` for the navigation bar if it doesn't show. Again, thanks a lot! :)